# How can I use filter in more than one ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

**HTML Code** This is used for display images in grid. 
 I used this link -- http://codepen.io/pulkitsinghal/pen/JjmED/

In this i used 5 ng-repeat tags but i got errors on filter **ng-repeat="row in f.images | inSlicesOf:2"**

```
    <div class="list itemnew card" ng-repeat="group in groups">
                        <ion-item class="item item-icon-right" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}" style="">
                            <i class="ion-chevron-right pull-right" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-chevron-down' : 'ion-chevron-right'" style="float:right;"><input type="hidden" ng-model="group.menu_name"></i> &nbsp; {{group.menu_name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div ng-switch on="group.menuid">                          

                                <!--Facilitites-->
                                 <div ng-switch-when="8">
                                    <ion-item class="item-accordion item ng-binding ng-hide " ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" style="">
                                        <div class="item bdr-none blue-light" style="margin-top:25px !important;">
                                            <div ng-repeat="facility in group.facilities">
                                                <div ng-repeat="f in facility">
                                                    <h2 class="padding-left">{{f.facilities_name}}</h2>
                                                    <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in f.images | inSlicesOf:2">
                                                        <div class="col col-50" ng-repeat="item in row">
                                                            <img src="{{item.img_name}}" class="col col-30" ng-click="showImage('{{item.img_name}}')" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </ion-item>
                                </div>



                            </div><!--Switch-->
                        </ion-item>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end ngRepeat: item in group.items -->
```

**Controller**
This in controller where i put my filter.

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ionic']);
app.filter('inSlicesOf', ['$rootScope',
  function ($rootScope) {
        makeSlices = function (items, count) {
            if (!count)
                count = 3;

            if (!angular.isArray(items) && !angular.isString(items)) return items;

            var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                var chunkIndex = parseInt(i / count, 10);
                var isFirst = (i % count === 0);
                if (isFirst)
                    array[chunkIndex] = [];
                array[chunkIndex].push(items[i]);
            }

            if (angular.equals($rootScope.arrayinSliceOf, array))
                return $rootScope.arrayinSliceOf;
            else
                $rootScope.arrayinSliceOf = array;

            return array;
        };

        return makeSlices;
  }]);

  app.controller('AboutUsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicModal) {
    $scope.groups = [];

    if (window.localStorage.getItem("about") !== null) {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem("about") !== "undefined") {
            $scope.groups = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("about"));
        }
    }

    $http.post("json")
        .success(function (response) {
            if (response.about === undefined) {
                if (window.localStorage.getItem("about") !== "undefined") {
                    $scope.groups = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("about"));
                }
            } else {
                $scope.groups = response.about;
                window.localStorage.removeItem("about");
                window.localStorage.setItem("about", JSON.stringify(response.about));
            }

        }).error(function (data) {
            if (window.localStorage.getItem("about") !== "undefined") {
                $scope.groups = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("about"));
            }
        });

    $scope.toggleGroup = function (group) {
        if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
            $scope.shownGroup = null;
        } else {
            $scope.shownGroup = group;
        }
    };

    $scope.isGroupShown = function (group) {
        return $scope.shownGroup === group;
    };

});
```

**Error in console**
For the preference purpose

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fkbs-test.com%2Fimages%2Fpages%2Fimg13.jpg%22%7D%5D%5D
    at Error (native)
    at 127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…-a621-2128fb7dbab1/platforms/ios/www/js/angular/ionic.bundle.min.js:37:416
    at n.$digest (127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…-a621-2128fb7dbab1/platforms/ios/www/js/angular/ionic.bundle.min.js:164:96)
    at n.$apply (127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…a621-2128fb7dbab1/platforms/ios/www/js/angular/ionic.bundle.min.js:166:269)
    at HTMLBodyElement. (127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…a621-2128fb7dbab1/platforms/ios/www/js/angular/ionic.bundle.min.js:137:115)
    at HTMLBodyElement.Gf.c (127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…-a621-2128fb7dbab1/platforms/ios/www/js/angular/ionic.bundle.min.js:66:217)
    at n (127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…-a621-2128fb7dbab1/platforms/ios/www/js/angular/ionic.bundle.min.js:22:384)
    at t (127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…-a621-2128fb7dbab1/platforms/ios/www/js/angular/ionic.bundle.min.js:22:216)
    at HTMLDocument.l (127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…a621-2128fb7dbab1/platforms/ios/www/js/angular/ionic.bundle.min.js:22:1451)

Comment: first of all next time post the error... infinite digest loop secondly Im not sure what the arrayinSliceOf does but are you sure it doesnt rerun the entire repeater? this is one way to have an infinite loop

Comment: yes it work for me before but in current scenario it goes in infinite loop

Comment: So are you sure that the return does not change some watch variable or something that reruns the loop?

Comment: No. Actually, Not sure i am in trouble how to resolve this

Comment: can you create a plunker?